# Why is this question on hold?

Tags: discussion, closing, game-identification

There is [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/153495/42984) that is currently on hold.  From the comments, it seems that it is on hold as "unclear what you're asking" but it is currently on hold as off-topic for game identification.

However, the question contains a screenshot.  Judging by the change log for it, the screenshot was added 5 hours before being put on hold the second time.

So are we just ignoring the site policy where it says "We allow an exception for identifying games based on an actual piece of the game, such as screenshots or audio clips"?

As for the argument that it should be closed for "unclear what you're asking", I would think the title and the game-identification tag make it pretty clear that the OP wants the name of the game.

Comment: Take a closer look at the timeline of that edit history and the related comments. OP doesn't want the name of the game anymore, he got it, and the screenshot was added *after* that fact. Editing in the screenshot doesn't really improve the internet as a repository of knowledge, does nothing to further help the OP, and undermines the *actual* purpose of the exception, by turning it into cutesy end-run around the existing rules by playing guessing games in the comments section.

Comment: ^ post that as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That question really isn't asking what game is in the screenshot. Nowhere in the entire body of it is the screenshot mentioned. And I'm not saying that as quibbling over wording; the screenshot, in fact, is the *answer*.

No, seriously; it was added in, and the title of the game was added to the question title,  after someone guessed it in the comments. I reverted back the game name being in the title, because answers **really** shouldn't be in the question, and it also got re-opened for answering, but ultimately, the question still isn't asking what the screenshot is about; it's just an answer sitting in the middle of the question.

And honestly, there's really no use in reopening it at this point; it was a terrible off-topic question, that only remotely got salvaged by people figuring out the answer. And someone knowing the answer doesn't redeem bad questions. The OP has his answer, and we're not going to help anyone by keeping this around.

Answer (score 13):

**Site Policy Rule #1:** We don't allow Identify This Game questions.

**Site Policy Rule #2:** We allow one single exception, for when the question asker has a concrete artifact from the game.

**Abusing Rule #2:** Retroactively adding a concrete artifact after the game has been identified in the comments, for the express purpose of making a question that violates rule #1 fit in under rule #2.